# After using XmlSerializer on the class, it loses some of the properties when returned back to the caller

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, xmlserializer

I'm using `XmlSerializer` to serialize a web reference object given by the 3rd party.

When sending the class to `XmlSerializer` constructor, it has all the properties with the value it was assigned to.

However, after getting it back from `XmlSerializer`, some properties are still there and some are lost.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
MerchantWSBO merchantWSBO = BuildMerchantObject(merchantInsertRow);//building an object from a database
string xmlToSend = ClassToXML(merchantWSBO );//merchantWSBO is a remote object supplied by the 3rd party.
```

After executing it, `xmlToSend` xml string doesn't have the needed properties.

That's the object's structure definition pertaining to the the property I'm talking about:

`MerchantWSBO` object contains a private property of a type MerchantWSVO`:

`private MerchantWSVO overviewField;

This `overviewField` property is a type `MerchantWSVO` which contains the public property that I'm referring to in this questions and which is missing after the serialization.

And that's how `overviewField` is accessed:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public MerchantWSVO overview {
        get {
            return this.overviewField;
        }
        set {
            this.overviewField = value;
        }
    }
```

That's how the missing property is defined in a `MerchantWSVO` object:

```
/// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public System.Nullable<bool> discoverRetained {
            get {
                return this.discoverRetainedField;
            }
            set {
                this.discoverRetainedField = value;
            }
        }
```

So, when building the object, I have the following code in `BuildMerchantObject` method:

```
BuildMerchantObject(DataRow merchantInsertRow)
{
     MerchantWSBO merchantWSBO = new MerchantWSBO();         
     MerchantWSVO merchantWSVO = new MerchantWSVO();
     merchantWSVO.discoverRetained = Convert.ToBoolean(merchantInsertRow["DiscoverRetained"].ToString().Trim());
     merchantWSBO.overview = merchantWSVO;
     return merchantWSBO;
}
```

`discoverRetained` property is missing from an xml string after serialization.

What I noticed though is that one of the available properties after the serialization is defined in `MerchantWSVO` as following: `private string binBlockingIndicatorField`;

But the property that's missing is defined as following: `private System.Nullable<bool> discoverRetainedField; Bu from the database it's coming with a value` true`

What can be the issue here, since some of the properties are available and some are note

Comment: Depending on the type the XML serialize doesn't not output a tag. Numbers when null do get tags but string do not.

Comment: questions: a: what does the xml look like? is `<discoverRetained>...</discoverRetained>` in there, with some value? b: are either of the following well-known patterns defined? `discoverRetainedSpecified` (property of type `bool`) or `ShouldSerializediscoverRetained` (method returning `bool`)?

Comment: @MarcGravell xml doesn't output anything for that property. I verified it, and only the `System.Nullable<bool>` and `bool` properties are note getting retrieved at all after serialization

Comment: and once again: is there a `ShouldSerializediscoverRetained` etc? have you manually run instances with values `null`, `true` and `false` through `XmlSerializer` to see what it outputs? what *exactly* does it output? without details, we can only guess, and guessing is rarely useful

Comment: @MarcGravell There is no `ShouldSerializediscoverRetained`. I haven't run manually with `null`,`true` and `false`, but all the properties defined as `String` in the remote object are being serialized. The xml doesn't have any tags related to discoverRetained. That field is just ignored

Comment: @MarcGravell Also, the class with a `Nullable` property is a remote class provided by a 3rd party. And I cannot really modify it

Comment: @gene yet a quick test here shows that `XmlSerializer` *doesn't* ignore this - i.e. `<X>true</X><Y>false</Y><Z xsi:nil="true" />` from [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAJVMA6ADQFsAbMgZQFMwBLAQxpYC83gWB7KAG48ANzZgi/AEYArIgF4iURgHciAYSIBvCoqLBIjGEQCa+gGYcAzsaIAtfVAg0aAXxG4V66jSasObmYACmAATwAHRn4LYI0ASniGZnZOLkY4wWt+GkYyAHkIYBMZWXjPPFQAZhJ0TR08IiaiAG1fAFFcqkYoYGCASWsAORcaNmlc/UMIRniAXRIa6X4cgH4iPW0Ac0ZgIVs9t0bmttpOxm7egeHR8cmladmF6qJltbMdHb2DoSPcZtaHS6PT6gxGrjujCmRnmi1eKxo60c212+1RfzcQA===) - so: without a runnable example: we're back to guessing

Comment: @MarcGravell Interesting. Could that be a reason that the property being serialized belongs to the type defined in the `MerchantWSBO` class?

Comment: @MarcGravell I just tested a console app where I created a web service reference to the same objects, assigned a `true` value the same way as it's done in my original code and tried to serialize it. Everything works fine and I can get an XML string with the value I need. But, it doesn't work in my original code